# Linux application freeze on boost::thread::join

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, boost

I am currently porting our c++ qt app to linux which was developed in MSVC and it keeps freezing on some threading operations. In windows, everything works fine. Our thread implementation uses the following code (excerpt):

**thread.h:**

```
class our_thread
{
    public:
        our_thread();
        ~our_thread();

        void run(boost::thread*);
        void join(const char* = 0);
        inline bool is_running() const;

    private:
        void delete_thread();

        bool thread_is_running;
        boost::thread* thread_object;
};
```

**thread.cpp:**

```
void our_thread::run(boost::thread* t)
{
    this->delete_thread();
    this->thread_object = t; 
    this->thread_is_running = true;
    QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::BusyCursor);   
    plot("in run");
}

void our_thread::join(const char* text)
{
    plot("in join");
    if(this->thread_object == 0) { return; }
    this->thread_is_running = false;
    QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
    if(text)
    {
        plot(text);
    }
    progress.show(false);
    this->thread_object->join();
    this->delete_thread();
}

void our_thread::delete_thread()
{
    this->thread_is_running = false;
    delete this->thread_object;
    this->thread_object = 0;
}
```

**and the call for instance:**

```
this->do_something_thread.run(new boost::thread(&function_name, this, param1));
...
this->do_something_thread.join("Part creation finished");
```

The `plot()` calls are user information but here also used for debug output.

Now, for some operations, this procedure always works, for some it always freezes the app after all the code in the thread is finished and the `join()` is called. If I debug the software and step through the code, it magically works flawless until I try to use the thread again. Then it directly freezes on the `run()` call.

I tried boost 1.39.0 and 1.49.0 without any difference. We are using RedHat 5.4 and everything is compiled with gcc44.

**Edit:**
I want to emphasize that everything works fine on windows so I don't think this is a simple code error. More like a linux specific thing as some compiler specific setting or flag or whatever that may create such a bug.

Comment: you never call `this->thread_object->run()`. What is the purpose of thread_is_running ?

Comment: Do you use **any** synchronization primitives? Just as one example, how do you know what are the compiler optimizations and the memory model applicable to the `thread_is_running` boolean?

Comment: @mockinterface the "thread_is_running" value is only touched from the caller, so if the "our_thread" object is always accessed from the same thread, why would there be any synchronization? Anyways, `thread_is_running` is a write-only variable in this code.

Comment: the `thread_is_running` flag is not really in use at the moment. I should probably have mentioned that the thread code was implemented by a coworker who is out of office for 6 weeks at the moment and I have not really worked a lot with threads so far

Comment: Try and find a way of keeping your coworker out of the office to prevent any further harm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that we were joining the thread from within the thread itself. In version 1.54, this is throwing an exception telling us that doing so would cause a deadlock. Such an exception is apparently not thrown in the older versions (while also not causing a deadlock for whatever reason). After calling the join from outside of the thread this is now working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you are using complicated manual memory management and redundant boolean flags (if there is a thread, it must be joined, the boolean is redundant and unused).

However, I also don't see the room for deadlock.

Here's a self-contained version that shows it "working" **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a067192bae889ac8)**

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

void plot(std::string msg)
{
    static boost::mutex mx;
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lk(mx);

    std::cout << msg << "\n";
}

class our_thread
{
    public:
        our_thread() : thread_object(0), thread_is_running(false) {}
        ~our_thread(){delete_thread();}

        void run(boost::thread*);
        void join(const char* = 0);
        inline bool is_running() const;

    private:
        void delete_thread();

        bool thread_is_running;
        boost::thread* thread_object;
};

void our_thread::run(boost::thread* t)
{
    this->delete_thread();
    this->thread_object = t; 
    this->thread_is_running = true;
    plot("in run");
}

void our_thread::join(const char* text)
{
    plot("in join");
    if(this->thread_object == 0) { return; }
    this->thread_is_running = false;
    if(text)
    {
        plot(text);
    }
    plot("progress.show(false);");
    this->thread_object->join();
    this->delete_thread();
}

void our_thread::delete_thread()
{
    this->thread_is_running = false;
    delete this->thread_object;
    this->thread_object = 0;
}

void function_name(std::string param1)
{
    plot("Enter function_name");
    plot(param1);
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(3));
    plot("Leave function_name");
}

int main()
{
    our_thread do_something_thread;
    do_something_thread.run(new boost::thread(&function_name, "param1"));
    // ...
    do_something_thread.join("Part creation finished");
}
```

Can you work out the minimal change that shows your problem? Then maybe you can spot what is the cause.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am not really sure what you mean by "Can you work out the minimal change that shows your problem?" We always only use the two calls to `our_thread` and for some methods it works, for some it doesn't

Comment: Then, can you check that my program works "right"? Subsequently introduce more things that resemble your application, right until the problem occurs. Then you'll either know the problem, or exactly what to ask.

Comment: I can try that but its not that easy as we are performing extensive three dimensional geometric operations using third part libraries in the thread so there are a lot if includes to be made. Probably should not have asked the question on a Friday afternoon^^

Comment: @Bowdzone I don't mind. It's just - we can't help much more without more information

Comment: ..and that is such a common problem, right there - asking us to 'debug' incomplete code that requires a complex environment that we don't have on a box we don't have with libs we don't have and a debugger we don't have and a logger we don't have.

Comment: @MartinJames And that's fine too. I'm happy to help people get started. Slightly bummed if they get discouraged/give up hope. And yes, such a question is only marginnnnnnninininallissimally useful to others - so it doesn't get my upvotes.

Comment: @MartinJames except from probably not being allowed to post it...if I'd post all the code that happens in the thread nobody would even read the question, not to mention describing all the includes and so on. So I tried to break it down to only whats required. If I could add some information you would like to have I'll happily provide it.

Comment: @Bowdzone - oh, I understand NDA and not wanting to post walls of code that we would also moan about:)  Nevertheless, you should understand that if it's so difficult for you to find the bug/s with the tools etc. at your disposal, it's almost impossible for us:(

Comment: @MartinJames yeah I was just hoping for some small thing I probably don't know about like a compilerflag or something.